# Is it a good idea to have many keyspaces and potentially thousands of tables in Cassandra?

Tags: database-design, cassandra, bigdata, database

So, I've been using Cassandra for a while and the architecture of the database is designed in a way that is fairly unusual to me. The fact is I just don't have enough knowledge to decide if that's a good design or not as I'm new to this whole Big Data thing.

Here's a simplification:

- We have vendors
- Each vendor have clients
- For each vendor, we create their own keyspace in Cassandra.
- For each client of the vendor, we create approximately 12-15 tables in its vendor's keyspace. Something like `clientid_TableName`.
- Tables are created dynamically when a client is created. This is slow and I'm afraid Cassandra will fail to propagate schema when is under load of all other operations.
- All the table have the same schema, there is no special modelling for any given client.
- Due to the nature of our data, around 5 of these tables can potentially have millions, if not billions, of rows.

Because of the distributed nature of Cassandra, I would never think that such "manual" division of data would be needed or even *beneficial*.

This single application will have dozens of keyspaces and potentially thousands of tables **per** keyspace. Won't this impact performance negatively?

The impression I was given is that this design allows to spread data more evenly, causing *less* performance impact when searching within a single table. It didn't make much sense to me, but I didn't have any arguments to counter it as my experience with Cassandra and so-called design for big data is, at best, very limited. The only benefit I can really think of is to have different keyspace settings per vendor. But I don't think that trumps any of the added complexity.

In short, was this a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you moving from RDBMS to Cassandra, you probably will have to re-design your ERD, and in most cases, moving standard, and normalized schema is a very bad decision. Right now you trying just to move existing schema to Cassandra.

You have all this table creation per vendor etc. workflow. You need to understand why you are working this way, and if you need this in Cassandra at all. In general you can have many tables, and many keyspaces (there are limits, but they are high) but probably this will not fit Cassandra modeling at all.

In Cassandra, you should build your tables **based on queries** and not entity,object,relation etc... Data duplication is not considered a problem, but a trade off between performance and storage needed.

I suggest you to take the course about data modeling in Cassandra from Datastax. It's a great course, and it's totally free::

https://academy.datastax.com/courses

Comment: Yes, the schema is mostly denormalized, that's not a problem. The tables are all designed thinking of the queries and partitions. My question relates more about the odd choices of having many keyspaces and many tables all with the same structure, if that won't impact performance negatively. My point is that we create a set of tables with the same structure for every single client we have. Thanks.

Comment: It should not impact performance, and anyway you can create additional level of abstraction with running several clusters with many keyspaces with many tables... My point is, probably, with proper design in Cassandra you wouldn't need all this schema per client design at all.

Comment: I agree. But if there's no performance impact then I can't really help it, it's their choice and I don't really have a say on it. Mind you: I absolutely disagree with this schema, I think it brings huge complexities without any benefit. Thanks!